# Every function in seperated js files but included only if used

Tags: javascript, performance

Hey all im trying something (because im boring) every function as js files can be used but if only needed file will bi apended. so i have write something like this. some parts from this site.

library.js:

```
var jsfiles = new Array(
    "jsLibrary/try.js",
    "jsLibrary/try2.js"
);

var loadedJsFiles = [];

function loadFile(filepath,callback){
    var head = document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0];
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.type = 'text/javascript';
    script.src = filepath;
    script.onreadystatechange = callback;
    script.onload = callback;
    head.appendChild(script);
}

function loadalljs(callback,jsnum){
    if(!jsnum){jsnum = 0;}
    if(jsnum<jsfiles.length){
        if(!isArrayNode(jsfiles[jsnum],loadedJsFiles)){
            loadedJsFiles.push(jsfiles[jsnum]);
            loadFile(jsfiles[jsnum],function(){
                loadalljs(callback,jsnum+1);    
            });
        }else{
            loadalljs(callback,jsnum+1);
        }
    }else if(jsnum==jsfiles.length){
        callback();
    }
}

function isArrayNode(str, arr) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (str == arr[i]) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function lb(){
    this.scripts = function(callback,includePageJs){
        loadalljs(function(){
            if(includePageJs){
                loadFile(includePageJs,function(){
                    callback(); 
                })
            }else{
                callback();
            }
        }); 
    };
    this.a = 5;
}

var library = new lb;
```

try.js:

```
function tryfunction(){
    alert("try");   
}
```

try2.js:

```
function try2(){
    alert("try2");  
}
```

mypage.js:

```
function mypagefunction(){
    alert("mypagejs");  
}
```

and im using it like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="jsLibrary/library.js"></script>
<script>
    library.scripts(function(){
        tryfunction();
        try2();
        mypagefunction();
    },"jsLibrary/mypagejs.js");

    library.scripts(function(){
        alert(library.a)
    });
</script>
```

is there any way to do this with easy way? thanks for any idea or help. (Not in jquery please)

Comment: You might want to check out http://requirejs.org/ - Does similar to what you want.

Comment: its a good page thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [Requirejs](http://requirejs.org/)

```
<script>
  requirejs.config({
    paths: {
      'try1': '../path_to_your_try.js',
      'try2': '../path_to_your_try2.js',
      'mypage': '../path_to_your_mypage.js',
    }  
  });

  require([
    'try1', 'try2', 'mypage'
  ], function(Try1, Try2, MyPage){

    // Try1 refer to try1 file
    // Try2 refer to try2 file
    // MyPage refer to mypage file

  });
</script>
```